# How do I specify a range in a Sequelize table?

Tags: sequelize.js

How do I specify a range between 0.0 and 4.0 in the gpa column in the table below?

```
 const Student = db.define('student', {
      firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
        allowNull: false,
      },
      gpa: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this can help you to validate :

```
const Student = db.define('student', {
    ...
    gpa: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
        validate: {
            min: 0,
            max: 4
        }
    }
    ...
})
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#model-validations)**